# Как понять что нужно сайтам для авторизации, что куда отправлять?

Tags: http, post

Я пишу сайт в котором можно было бы собрать аккаунты с других сайтов. Своего рода пульт управления различными аккаунтами.

Не могу понять, как разобраться в системах авторизации на посторонних сайтах. Использовал для этого инструменты разработчика от гугл хром, wiresharke, везде останавливаюсь на том, что сайт выдает кучу скриптов, нахожу один который содержит логин и пароль при авторизации. Посылаю на него логин, пароль, куки. И все. Дальше ничего не происходит.

Код не привожу, поскольку написано просто банальное http соединение.

Если я правильно понимаю, при успешной авторизации в ответ должна приходить ссылка на страницу пользователя, токен, sessionID, и со всем этим только можно нормально авторизоваться. Вот этого не происходит.

Как вообще понять что нужно любому сайту для авторизации, что куда отправлять? Может есть какие-нибудь способы, как это правильно делать.

Я использую Apache HttpClient java, так же пробовал стандатрный HttpURLConnection. Пробовал javascript

```
window.open("http://www.site.com").document.getElementById("ID").onclick (submit, click).
```

Сайты, на которых я пытался авторизоваться: vk.com, ok.ru, uber.com, yandex.ru

Comment: Спасибо большое за комментарий. Сейчас добавлю в вопрос все, что Вы сказали.

Comment: Спасибо большое Krom Stern за помощь в редактировании вопроса. Я постараюсь в будущем быть более понятным.

Comment: Вы собираетесь хранить пароли пользователей от других сервисов у себя (а-ля keepass)? Или только связку создавать?

Comment: Только связку создавать. Я недостаточно еще силен в безопасности, что бы доверить себе хранить пароли.

Comment: Тогда нужно изучать API каждого сайта в отдельности. Какие параметры он хочет на входе, какие дает на выходе. Вам тогда надо раздробить вопрос по каждому сервису отдельно. Попробуйте сделать сначала что-то одно, например, vk.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ. Не могли бы Вы подсказать с чего лучше начинать изучение API?

Comment: По VK можно здесь посмотреть - http://vk.com/dev/openapi

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое еще раз. Буду разбираться.